# Am i misunderstanding what fabtools.service.is_running does?

Tags: python, fabric, upstart

am i misunderstanding fabtools?

when i run:

```
status some-service
```

it replies

```
some-service stop/waiting
```

but when i run:

```
def blah():
    if fabtools.service.is_running('some-service'):
        print "some-service is running!"
```

it says that it is running, when i clearly know it is not. Have i misunderstood what the function 'is_running' does?

EDIT:

looking at the source code:

```
def is_running(service):
    """
    Check if a service is running.

    ::

        import fabtools

        if fabtools.service.is_running('foo'):
            print "Service foo is running!"
    """
    with settings(hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'), warn_only=True):
        res = sudo('service %(service)s status' % locals())
        return res.succeeded
```

it still confuses me in the sense that what it seems to check if the service is there not whether it is running

Comment: What is the target machine os ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The implementation only checks if the service exists and not the status.
I modified the line to read:

```
res = sudo('service {} status|grep "running"'.format(service))
```

...and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`fabtools.service.is_running` indeed works now.

See the below when I've stopped `kibana` service and running this in python command line mode:

```
>>> fabtools.service.is_running('kibana')
False
```

When I have started `kibana` service, it returns true

```
>>> fabtools.service.is_running('kibana')
True
```